# PowerEdge R440 Mixed Memory configuration

Tags: memory, dell

I have one Dell PowerEdge R440

The server has 12 DIMM: 32GB 2Rx4PC4-266V-RB2-12(HMA84GR7JJR4N-VK)

```
[A6]-[A5]-[A10]-[A4]-[A9]---CPU0---[A7]-[A1]-[A8]-[A2]-[A3]
32Gb 32Gb       32Gb                    32Gb      32Gb 32Gb

[B3]-[B2]-[B1]---CPU1---[B4]-[B5]-[B6]
32Gb 32Gb 32Gb          32Gb 32Gb 32Gb
```

So I want to add 4 DIMM: 64GB 2Rx4 PC4-2933Y-RB3-12(HMAA8GR7MJR4N-WM TG AA 1951)

I follow the [Dell EMC PowerEdge R440 Installation and Service Manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/poweredge-r440/per440_ism_pub/dell-emc-poweredge-r440-system-overview?guid=guid-ae5bf17f-6584-46b5-8e94-43bb097897b6&lang=en-us), and I have tried various combinations and they don't work, like

```
adding to black block
[A6]-[A5]-[A10]-[A4]-[A9]---CPU0---[A7]-[A1]-[A8]-[A2]-[A3]
32Gb 32Gb 64Gb  32Gb 64Gb          64Gb 32Gb 64Gb 32Gb 32Gb

[B3]-[B2]-[B1]---CPU1---[B4]-[B5]-[B6]
32Gb 32Gb 32Gb          32Gb 32Gb 32Gb

or  adding to white block
[A6]-[A5]-[A10]-[A4]-[A9]---CPU0---[A7]-[A1]-[A8]-[A2]-[A3]
32Gb 32Gb 32Gb  32Gb 32Gb          32Gb 64Gb 32Gb 64Gb 32Gb

[B3]-[B2]-[B1]---CPU1---[B4]-[B5]-[B6]
32Gb 64Gb 64Gb          32Gb 32Gb 32Gb
```

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: How do they not work?

Comment: What the 2 and 3 in the RB2-12 and RB3-12 stands for? I googled and saw these might be memory timings, but can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is HMAA8GR7MJR4N-WM TG AA 195(64GB 2Rx4 PC4-2933Y-RB3-12),These DIMMs aren't compatibilty beacuse the CPU ( Xeon Gold 6140 processors)  only run  2666 QUAD RANK. So I'm process to change it.